# Mean and standard deviation of Gaussian Distribution

Tags: estimation, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation

I have some random numbers which are generated from Gaussian Distribution. But I don't know the mean, standard deviation of that distribution. How can I find them using random numbers?

Comment: If the only thing you have available to you is the sample of random numbers, this is impossible. But you can estimate them by computing the empirical mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @ocram Yeah, I have only large amount of random numbers generated from Gaussian Distribution.

Comment: Then, both the mean and variance can be estimated from your sample. @David Robinson has clarified that point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can estimate them. The best estimate of the mean of the Gaussian distribution is the mean of your sample- that is, the sum of your sample divided by the number of elements in it.

$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$

The most common estimate of the standard deviation of a Gaussian distribution is

$$\bar{s} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \bar{x}\right)^2}.$$

Here, $x_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ number in your sample. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) for details.

Comment: Thanks, edited to add this. But of course you meant to add 1/n.